# Combine many Maven goals within a single one

Tags: java, maven

Until now, I'm using the command `mvn clean compile hibernate3:hbm2java` to launch my program. Is there any way to combine those three goals within a single one, e.g. `mvn run` or `mvn myapp:run`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another solution that differs completely from my other answer would be to use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) with the goal [`exec:exec`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <executable>mvn</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>clean</argument>
                    <argument>compile</argument>
                    <argument>hibernate3:hbm2java</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then you just run it like this:

```
mvn exec:exec
```

By doing it this way you are not changing any of the other plugins and it is not bound to any phases either.

Comment: I wanted to have the same, and I was really really thinking to put back in place a makefile. But I thought.. there should be a maven solution.. so you are saying indeed that it is not there?? As, exec, if I get it right from the name and the fact that there is <executable> will "exec"!.. so not really easy to manage steps, dependencies and return codes..  Is it really the case with maven? I cannot chain targets? I mean with a bit of control?

Comment: Just googled it again and found this 2005 doc: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Multiple+Goal+Declaration

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for!
Note: Version 1.5.0 is kind of broken on windows. See - https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/42 So avoid that if you want to use it there. Use the previous version 1.4.0 or an updated version > 1.5.0 when they release one

Comment: Although this works, this is totally working around the maven ecosystem. Plugins bind to a phase for a reason and this is just using maven to execute maven? As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820066/1208786 there is a better way to have the plugin run during a standard build; it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define a **default goal** for Maven build.
Then your command line call will look like this

```
mvn
```

**Defining default goal**

Add the following lines to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>clean compile hibernate3:hbm2java</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

Comment: It is also possible to put the default goal into a profile, so you can run the program with `mvn -Prun` if you don't want to modify the default build.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Hibernate3 Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2java-mojo.html) site the `hbm2java` goal binds to the `generate-sources` phase by default.

And normally you won't have to clean the project, you run incremental builds.

Anyway if you add the `maven-clean-plugin` and the `hibernate3-maven-plugin` in your `pom.xml` you will have it all in one command.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2java</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you want the `hibernate3-maven-plugin` to be run after `compile` then just set the goal to `compile` since it will always run after default phases.

So to run all your goals with one command just run:

```
mvn compile
```

And if you for any reason don't want to clean then just type:

```
mvn compile -Dclean.skip
```

Comment: And if you don't want it to always run `hbm2java`, then place that (and maybe the `clean`) plugin inside a [profile](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-what.html), i.e. `mvn compile -Phbm`

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but this should be the accepted answer. The mvn exec:exec solution is not what I would accept as the solution for any of our maven builds.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to use [`maven-invoker-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html), like :

```xml
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <pom>pom.xml</pom>
                    <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-app</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>clean</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:hbm2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

You can then invoke your command with :

```bash
mvn invoker:run@run-app
```

One advantage of this solution: your active `mvn` properties (e.g. using profiles) are propagated to given goals, which is not the case with `maven-exec-plugin`.