# It's possible to run docker container and a spring boot application at the same time in maven?

Tags: spring, maven, docker, spring-boot, fabric8

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to a MongoDB instance. For MongoDB instance I use a docker, specifically I use the maven docker plugin from fabric8. I have this configuration:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <logDate>default</logDate>
                <autoPull>true</autoPull>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>mongo:3.0.15</name>
                        <run>
                            <ports>
                                <port>27018:27017</port>
                            </ports>
                            <wait>
                                <log>(?s)database system is ready to accept connections.*database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                <time>40000</time>
                            </wait>
                            <log>
                                <prefix>mongo-container</prefix>
                                <color>yellow</color>
                            </log>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It works perfectly if I run mvn docker:start and in other terminal mvn spring-boot:run.

What I want to know is if it's possible to create some maven configuration to run this on a single command like mvn docker:start spring-boot:run.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819773/combine-many-maven-goals-within-a-single-one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine many Maven goals within a single one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819773/combine-many-maven-goals-within-a-single-one)

Comment: Thanks for the help, It could be a solution. However with a configuration like: <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>mvn</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>docker:start</argument>
                        <argument>spring-boot:run</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
The execution of docker:start blocks the spring-boot:run...