# undeploy jboss cli fails if the war not exists

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, command-line-interface

I am trying to undeploy and deploy war file with jboss-as-maven-plugin to jboss EAP 6 and have mentioned the below lines in my project pom.xm. The Undeploy cli steps fails if the WAR is not already deployed and available in jboss . i am expecting this to be skip if the WAR not present and proceed with new deployment in next steps. Any idea to fix this ?

```html
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:execute-commands (unassign-war) on project chexreseller: Execution unassign-war of goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:execute-commands failed: Operation failed: {"domain-failure-description" => {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014807: Management resource '[
[ERROR]     (\"server-group\" => \"web-server-group\"),
[ERROR]     (\"deployment\" => \"xxx.war\")
[ERROR] ]' not found"}}}}}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]`
```

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.9.Final</version>
        <configuration>
   <timeout>60000</timeout>
   <username>${uname}</username>
            <password>${password}</password>
            <hostname>${hostname}</hostname> 
        </configuration>
        <executions>
    <execution>                      
     <id>upload-war</id>
     <phase>deploy</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals> 
                <configuration>
                    <deployEnabled>false</deployEnabled>
                    <force>true</force>
                        <domain>
                            <server-groups>
        <server-group>myservergrp</server-group>
                            </server-groups>
                        </domain>
                </configuration>
    </execution> 
    <execution>
     <id>unassign-war</id>
     <phase>deploy</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>execute-commands</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
      <executeCommands>
       <batch>true</batch>
        <commands>
         <command>undeploy xxx.war --server-groups=myservergrp</command>
         <command>undeploy yyy.war --server-groups=myservergrp</command> 
        </commands>
      </executeCommands>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
     <id>enable-this-war</id>
     <phase>deploy</phase>
     <goals>
      <goal>execute-commands</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
      <executeCommands>
       <batch>true</batch>
        <commands>
         <command>deploy --name=xxx.war --server-groups=myservergrp</command>
         <command>deploy --name=yyy.war --server-groups=myservergrp</command>
        </commands>
      </executeCommands>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to resolve by adding only the below lines in my pom.xml which will replace the deployed components and deploying new one if it is not there

```
            <executions>
            <execution>                      
                <id>upload-war</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals> 
            <configuration>
                <filename>xxx.war</filename>
                <deployEnabled>false</deployEnabled>
                <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
                <force>true</force>
                    <domain>
                        <server-groups>
                            <server-group>web-server-group</server-group>
                        </server-groups>
                    </domain>
            </configuration>
            </execution>    
        </executions>
```

Note: If you are not mentioning the filename tag then default project name will be taken for deployment

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but from reviewing the maven plugin documentation in https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/complex-example.html, I think you are simply missing an additional configuration sub-element, namely:

```
<configuration>
    <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tried adding this but still same exception , not sure what is to get tweaked

Comment: There are straightforward examples of using the maven plugin to undeploy and to deploy using seperate goals. Perhaps the better approach is to follow the guidance in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819773/combine-many-maven-goals-within-a-single-one to combine these goals to accomplish your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Adding the below lines is meeting my expectation to replace the deployed components